# <asp:Table> Vs html <table>

Tags: asp.net, html

What are the differences between the ASP.Net control `<asp:Table>` compared to the old reliable table HTML implementation?

I know that the `<asp:Table>` will end up on the returned page as a HTML table, but does the ASP.Net control come with any benefits that I'm missing?

Comment: I've never used an ASP:Table, and I've been a .Net developer since version 1.0.  I've never found a use for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A "regular" `<table>` is not available for modification *at all* on the server side. As far as the server-side is concerned, it's just static text that gets output to the browser.

I would say that as a general rule, favour `<table>` unless you explicitly need to modify the structure of the table on the server. Using `<asp:Table>` means you have the overhead of running the code-behind for the table, generating the server-side control and so on. If you're not using any of that functionality, then there's no point.

Also, in general, `<asp:DataTable>` is typically more useful than just plain `<asp:Table>`, since it supports data-binding and so on.

Usually, if I just want to show/hide a single row in a table (or something) then I'll just put `runat="server"` on the *single* `<tr>` that I want to control, rather than using a whole `<asp:Table>`.

Comment: Mentioning the runat="server" in the very last sentence makes this comment unhelpful. It should have been included in the first sentence, but then you'd be basically saying '<table/>' isn't available server side by '<asp:Table runat="server"/>', oh and so is '<table runat="server"/>". In which case, the discussion becomes whether to use System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table vs. System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable, which I think is a more useful discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that there are cases in which ASP HtmlTables cannot output standards-compliant HTML. For instance, they [do not support complete table semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.aspx) (thead/tfoot/tbody, cols, caption...); they'll throw an exception if you try to include those elements programmatically.

These are serious limitations for accessible content.